# How to implement multiple level (nested) component using ControlValueAccessor

Tags: angular, formarray, controlvalueaccessor

I have a complicate form which need 4~5 levels of nested form.
I have couple of  components, all of them implements ControlValueAccessor and the return type is an object array.
Instead of return a FormGroup, is there any way to return a FormArray so that I can use the multiple components to achieve multiple level nested form?

top level component:

```
...
    <app-a formControlName="level1"></app-a>
...
```

component A:

```
...
    <app-b formControlName="level2"></app-b>
...
```

component B:

```
...
    <app-c formControlName="level3"></app-c>
...
```

component C:

```
...
   <app-d formControlName="level4"></app-d>
...
```